# Not Just Black and White

Tags: word, cipher, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

Answer for this puzzle is one word. Have fun!

[image]

Highlighted parts are where I realised I have clued it wrong... Sorry for all this inconvenience!

Hint:

<sub>usefulness level 1</sub>

> The way of deciphering has been hinted in this post

<sub>usefulness level 2</sub>

> athin should have used another colour instead of yellow. That would make things easier, hopefully...

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Comment: I am fairly sure I have proved that this is _not_ solvable as an ordinary "just black and white" nonogram. So either that title needs to be taken seriously (though I confess I don't currently have any good ideas what else to do with it), or my reasoning is broken, or (by a long way the least likely of the three options) there's an error in the puzzle.

Comment: let me check @GarethMcCaughan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After solving the nonogram (from @athin)

The title,

> along with the binary found by solving the nonogram, clues Gray codes.

Breaking the code:

> We can construct the Gray code by starting with [0, 1], and each layer we can flip the entire list, append 0 to the front of each element in the original list, append 1 to the front of each element in the new list, and then concatenate the lists. So [0, 1] becomes [00, 01, 11, 10] for instance. For 5 bits, we get the list [image]
>  *(Ok, maybe I interpreted the word "flip" too literally).*
>  Anyway, I also wrote down the letters A-Z down the side starting 00000 (which makes sense given our code text contains some 00000's). Decoding the Gray code line by line gives the answer **VANADIUM**.

Comment: nice job, it's done! when do you want the green check?

Answer (score 6):

### Partial Answer

This is the completed nonogram:

> [image]

It seems like:

> They are binary numbers, either read horizontally or vertically.
>  But I don't know what next as converting them to ASCII results random characters..

Comment: rot13(Gur snpg gung gur fbyhgvba vf neenatrq va ebjf bs 5 znxrf zr guvax guvf zvtug npghnyyl or n Onpba pvcure. Ubjrire, gur fbyhgvba unf obgu 11111 naq 00000 fb bar bs gubfr gjb jba'g qrpbqr va Onpba. Znlor gur fjvgpu va pbybef vf zrnavatshy? gung zvtug fhttrfg syvccvat gur ovgf, gubhtu vg unccraf va gur zvqqyr bs n punenpgre.)

Comment: added hint, please check... nonogram is correct ;)